# Foreign Key relationship at second level

Tags: python, django

Suppose I have three models such as -

```
class company(models.Model):
    companyName = models.charField()

class branch(models.Model):
    branchName = models.charField()
    company = models.ForeignKey(company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Now in the third model, that is **customer** I want to have unique customer per compnay so I did -

```
class customers(models.Model):
    customerName = models.charField()
    branch= models.ForeignKey(branch, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company = models.ForeignKey(company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (
            ('company', 'customerName'),
        )
```

Now since the branch has already got **company** as a foreign field and I'm again using both **branch** and **company** in the **customers** model, will this form a cyclic structure, or is this a wrong way of doing it?

And if I remove the **company** from the **customers** model because **branch** already has **company** as a foreign field, how can I set unique customers per company at the database level?

Comment: Remove `company` from `customers`. A customer can only have one branch and a branch can only have one company, so a customer can only have one company

Comment: @IainShelvington I understand but how to avoid customerA - branchA and customerA - branchB case.  Should I manage elsewhere ?  or am I missing something?

Comment: `customers` is not a unique customer, there can be many `customers` with the same customerName but different branch?

Comment: customerName is for reference only, suppose email as an actual field, now the different company can have a customer with the same email but a single company must not have the same email twice.  so I can not make my field as unique=True.

Comment: for eg. - companyA - abc@gmail.com and companyB - abc@gmail.com should be allowed.

Comment: How could you have both customerA - branchA and customerA - branchB if branch is set as a foreign key? If you mean you could have 2 `customer_id` with the same name, each linked to a different branch, the put a restriction to make `customer_name` unique

Comment: @Christophe yes, I mean 2 customer_id with the same name (in real-world email). I can not make customerName unique because each name/email should be unique company-wise. means companyA can have name1 in only one of its branches. then companyB can again have name1 in one of its branches. This means if there are multiple branches of companyA only one of its branches can have name1.

Comment: You need to define precisely what you need end define your database accordingly. I mean, you allow several customers with the same name, but only one per company. The,, how information about these customers are managed? Is it one single customer with several e-mails are they linked one to the others? Your answers, and probably other considerations, might lead you to a solution, among foreign keys and/or functional checks (controls you could implement within your application). At this stage, one customer is already linked to a single company, as per customer_id.

Comment: trying explain via example;  customerName = abc, 2 different companies = companyA and companyB, and compnayA has branches = branch1, branch2, branch3 and compnayB has branches = branch4, branch5, branch6.  Now this abc customer should only be present in any one branch of companyA (either branch1,2 or 3) and then can also be present in any one branch of companyB (either branch 4,5 or 6). If a customer is present in any one branch of a company other branches of the same company can access the information. So I want unique customers per company. If again I am missing the point let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't create a cyclical structure, but you don't need `company` as an attribute.

You can access `company` through the `branch` foreign key.  This should work:

```
class customers(models.Model):
    customerName = models.charField()
    branch= models.ForeignKey(branch, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (
            ('branch__company', 'customerName'),
        )
```

Although, branch and customerName should theoretically be unique_together as well.

Comment: Tried this but this gives an error, **branch__company** is not a field. Well, will check again.